# how can i make a relation between master calss and student in my platform

Tags: php, laravel, relational-database, laravel-6

i want to create a platform by laravel 6  included classes  students an masters

masters can put the student's scores and the students can see them in their profile...

there is a many to many relation between classes and masters and between student and classes too.

the masters an students are not seperated and all of them store in user table and determine by his role_id

my big issue is uploading of scores by masters... i am extremely confused

has any one  any idea ?

Comment: In what format are the scores uploaded? CSV? Text file? Word document? Etc

Comment: no... any external file won't be uploaded.. the master put the grades by (requests) in store function @Savlon

Comment: So it’s a simple post request from your front end to your backend store function. What part of that are you having an issue with? Your question seems very broad and definitely needs refinement. Try to narrow down the problem a little more.

Answer (score 0):

What you might want to simplify things is an associative table of users, classes, and scores (I've drawn a diagram for you https://dbdiagram.io/d/5e9787f039d18f5553fdabb1). With this table, you can query pretty much all you could ever want.

Now all you need to do is configure privileges based on user role. A master can read from and write to all `class_user_score` entities where if there is a record of him being in a class, he can read and CRUD all `class_user_score` entities with the same `classId`. A student can only read `class_user_score` entities with his `userId` in them.

Unfortunately, I can't help you with the Laravel implementation (they also call an associative table a pivot table for some weird reason) since I'm more of a React, Nodejs type of guy, but I hope this at least helps you to reason about the problem.